# Bisection search in Python cant find the answer? Why does it result in negative balance?

Tags: python, payment, bisection

This code get down to -73535 and exits the loop. I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
balance = 999999   
annualInterestRate = 0.18   
epsilon = 0.05

monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12    
lowerBound = balance / 12    
upperBound = (balance * ((1 + monthlyInterestRate)**12)) / 12.0    
print(upperBound, lowerBound)   
currentBalance = balance    
middle = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2   

while abs(round(upperBound - lowerBound,2)) >= epsilon:    
    currentBalance = balance
    for i in range(12):
        unpaidBalance = currentBalance - middle
        currentBalance= unpaidBalance - (monthlyInterestRate * unpaidBalance)
    print(currentBalance)
    if abs(unpaidBalance) < 0.05:
        print("hahaha")
        break
    elif currentBalance < 0:
        upperBound = middle
    elif currentBalance > 0:
        lowerBound = middle
    middle = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2
```

Comment: In future, I would recommend following the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Style Guide as it is much more readable. Specifically, take a look at Naming conventions and whitespace in expressions and statements.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of the value you are apparently trying to converge, perhaps with a reference to the algorithm?

Comment: This is to try to figure out the minimum lowest payment I need to pay every month to pay off my credit card debt.I have to use bisection search.